# How to manually install 3rd party library in React Native without npm or yarn installer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I need to manually install 3rd party library. And there is any impact on build run and performance?

The library is https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple packages. some of them are only for development and some of them are needed in production too. for example think of eslint, a package for code quallity, in this package you do not need it in your production build, and only for developlemnt. but a package like chart.js is needed in your production build too.
so you need to decide that if a package is needed in your production build or not.
if its not needed you can add with

```
npm install --save-dev
```

the above code will only add the package in your development and wont bundle it with your production build

hope that helps

Comment: I need it in production. And the library's last update was 2 years ago. Like I said without npm I need to clone it in my codebase

Comment: it does'nt matter when it was updated if the last version is stable. just install it and use it.
but usually you can find a similar package that has been recently maintained

Comment: will it make a difference If I clone the library in my repo or install it through npm?

Comment: you can clone it and use it ofcourse. there are several ways of doing it, you can download the code from its github page, you can install it with your package manager in a seprete folder, and copy the code to where ever you want it to be.

Comment: can you please state the difference if I clone it from github or install it through npm? In my opinion both are same.

Comment: the difference is package management. in projects, you usually need to know what 3rd packages you installed, and what is the version of that package. but in reallity both of them download the package and you can use them. no difference in that part

Comment: There is no performance improvement in downloading 3rd parts libraries manually